# UpdatePanel, TriggerPostBack and UserControl How to load dynamically in TabPanel

Tags: vb.net, user-controls, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, tabpanel

okay?
I have a button that is inside an updatepanel, click on this button I'm trying to load an updatepanel updatepanel and inside this I have a usercontrol added. This is done dynamically'm not having success.
Could anyone help me?

```
    Protected Sub btnNewRpt_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNewRpt.Click
        Dim hydic As New HybridDictionary From {{"tabId", "tab1"},
                                                {"ucPath", "UCRelatorioNovo.ascx"},
                                                {"ucId", "uc1"}}

        buildControls(hydic)
    End Sub

Private Sub buildControls(ByVal hydic As HybridDictionary)
    Dim uc As UserControl = LoadControl(hydic("ucPath"))
    uc.ID = hydic("ucId")

    Dim tg As New PostBackTrigger With {.ControlID = uc.FindControl("btnLoadOtherUC").UniqueID}

    Dim up As New UpdatePanel With {.ID = "upTest"}
    up.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(uc)
    up.Triggers.Add(tg)

    Dim tp As New TabPanel With {.ID = hydic("tabId")}
    tp.Controls.Add(up)

    TabContainer1.Controls.Add(tp)
End Sub
```

the error description is: Could not find UpdatePanel with ID 'TabContainer1_tab1_upTest'. If it is being wellness updated dynamically then it must be inside another UpdatePanel.

Comment: Why are you adding update panel inside tab container ? Can't you place all these controls in aspx file instead of adding them dynamically ?

Comment: Because the user is who will decide how many usercontrols you want to open it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of placing UpdatePanel *upTest* inside TabContainer's TabPanel, place TabContainer/TabPanel inside *upTest* if you want to update them besides updating your custom control else you can place only the custom control inside *upTest*.

Comment: Coder, sorry I could not understand what you said. I need to create a new tab and inside an updatepanel and inside a usercontrol, remembering that everything must be dynamically.

Comment: Set UpdateMode of _upTest_ to _Conditional_ and ChildrenAsTriggers to _false_. See [http://forums.asp.net/t/1337905.aspx/1] and [http://forums.asp.net/t/1046285.aspx/2/10].